# Email Markup may not Work I using Amazon SES

Tags: email, jsonschema, google-schemas

Hello Guys I'm doing a email marketing with **json-ld** email markup the problem is that while sending test mail is not working, that is not the assigned button appears in the following code:

```
<body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "EmailMessage",
      "action": {
        "@type": "ViewAction",
        "url": "http://my-web-site-url-here.com",
        "name": "View Message"
      },
      "description": "View Message"
  }
</script>
```

For the above code I based on one I got in an email received, where it works.

You should see a button next to the email that says **"View Message"**

From already thank you very much!

Comment: If you're using email markup for marketing with Amazon SES, you'll have to register the email you're sending from in order for your Gmail users to see the action buttons. You can find more info on registering at the following (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google?hl=en).