# Unable to create google now card with email

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nodemailer, google-schemas, google-now

I'm trying to create the google now card with node.js and AWS SES.

my HTML is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "EventReservation",
          "reservationNumber": data_bookingId,
          "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
          "underName": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": data_userFirstName
          },
          "reservationFor": {
                "@type": "Event",
                "name": data_eventTitle,
                "startDate": data_startTime,
                "location": {
                      "@type": "Place",
                      "name": data_shortAddress,
                      "address": {
                            "@type": "PostalAddress",
                            "streetAddress": data_address1,
                            "addressLocality":data_address2,
                            "addressRegion": data_city,
                            "postalCode": data_pincode,
                            "addressCountry": "IN"
                      }
                }
          },
          "numSeats":data_numberOfReserves,
          "bookingAgent":{
            "image":data_featured_image
          }
    }
    </script>
    <p>
      Dear data_userFirstName, thanks for booking your data_eventTitle ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
      BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
      Order for: data_userFirstName <br/>
      Event: data_eventTitle <br/>
      When: data_startTime<br/>
      Venue: data_address1 , data_address2, data_city - data_pincode IN <br/>
      Reservation number: data_bookingId <br/>
    </p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

And my code is:

nowCard.html

```
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var aws = require('aws-sdk');
    var awsSesMail= function(mailOptions) {
        console.log("emailTemplate=====>\n",mailOptions.Message.Body.Html.Data);
        aws.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
        var ses = new aws.SES({
            apiVersion: '2012-10-17'
        });
        ses.sendEmail(mailOptions,function(err, data) {
            if (data) {
                print('Email sent:');
                print(data);
            } else {
                print('Email not sent:\n')
                print(err);
            }
        });
    };

    createGoogleNowCard = function (data) {

        var mapObj= {'data_bookingId':"BN-"+data.bookingId,data_userFirstName:data.userFirstName,data_eventTitle:data.eventTitle,data_startTime:data.startTime,data_shortAddress:data.shortAddress,data_address1:data.address1,data_address2:data.address2,data_city:data.city,data_pincode:data.pincode,data_numberOfReserves:data.numberOfReserves,data_featured_image:data.featured_image}

        //read the template file
        var emailTemplate = fs.readFileSync('./views/nowCard.html',"utf-8");

        var regexp = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");

        //replace the snippet with actual data    
        emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace(regexp, function(matched){
            return '"'+mapObj[matched]+'"';
        });

    var emailTemplate = fs.readFileSync('./nowCard.js',"utf-8");
        var mailOptions = {
                Source: 'xyz@gmail.com',
                Destination: {
                    ToAddresses: ['xyz@gmail.com']
                },
                Message: {
                    Subject: {
                        Data: "New Booking"
                    },
                    Body: {
                        Text: {
                            Data: "New Booking"
                        },
                        Html:{
                            Data:emailTemplate
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            awsSesMail(mailOptions);
    };
```

I'm sending the mail from xyz@domain.com to abc@domain.com, I'm getting the mail but google now card I'm not getting.
My mail is authenticated with the DIKM.

> Is it something wrong with AWS SES mail.

While I log the HTML file I'm getting the proper HTML file With the script.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Your message needs to be authenticated either by DKIM or SPF for the email actions to work. You can not set DKIM or SPF for gmail.com yourself, so you would have to send the message through Gmail SMTP and not through AWS SES

Comment: my email is authenticated with DKIM but I'm using the SES.

Comment: Your message can not be authenticated with DKIM because you do not know gmail.com private key for DKIM and SES doesn't know it either, only Gmail SMTP server knows it. So if you send messages from@gmail.com addresses through some other service then SPF and DKIM can never be valid.

Comment: sorry I mistakenly wrote @gmail.com my email is asd@domain.com

Comment: @vishnumishra You will have to register with Google to be able to send from xyz@domain.com to abc@domain.com. Check my comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792471/email-markup-may-not-work-i-using-amazon-ses

Comment: @Franco My email is already register with the gmail and verified with the DKIM.

Comment: What did you enter in the startDate field? If you've entered something that is still few days away, it will not trigger until the date specified. Are you seeing a Calendar entry for the user? Are you able to trigger an action button when including a modifyReservationUrl field?

Comment: @Franco I didn't got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to authenticate with DKIM or SPF **AND**
2. You need to register with Google.

Here's their page with the notice:

> To launch Google Now cards for your users, you will need to register
>   with Google. However, for the testing purposes, you can send emails to
>   yourself (from x@gmail.com to x@gmail.com) and your markup will be
>   displayed in Google products.

https://developers.google.com/schemas/tutorials/google-now-cards